# Inkscape - Draw path tangentially to an endpoint of a curve

Tags: inkscape

Okay so say I have a shape like this:

[image: Inkscape shape showing path selected]

Now I want to snap a new path to one of the corners and then extend it tangentially from the curve.

[image: Extending path from previous shape]
(This, but snapped to the tangent)

How do I do this? I know how to snap a line from an arbitrary point to a tangent of a curve but that doesn't exactly help when the start node of the line is one of the endpoints of the curve itself. But surely it's possible? I mean, you have the tangent at that point right there in the handle of the curve...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a method that should give you an accurate result, with no guessing or eyeballing.

1. Select the shape, and do *Extensions > Visualize Path > Draw handles*.

[image]

2. Select the drawn handles and do *Object > Objects to Guides*, or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

[image]

3. You can now use snapping to guides and cusp nodes to draw your new line. The Bézier handle will snap to the guide so you can match it with the angle of the Bézier handle of the original shape.

[image]

Comment: Wow. How come I never knew about object to guide???? This makes drafting so much easier!

Comment: Object to Guide is awesome. I've used it quite frequently with things like lengthening a line (Duplicate, Object to Guide, and then move endpoint along the line), or intersecting two lines into a larger shape (duplicate both lines, construct polygon with the intersection point.

Comment: Well, although I do actually find the way I detailed in my answer to be overall easier, I'll mark this because object to guides is something people might not know about. Thanks!

Comment: this is great, but how do i get ride of the helping lines afterwards. I cannot really select them. I can move them, but I cannot delete them in the intuitive way.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek You can mouse over a guide in Inkscape, when it turns red and the cursor changes to a hand, hit the Delete key. You can also click View and uncheck Guides to hide them.

Comment: @BillyKerr this is what I meant with the intuitive way of deleting. I found that others have a similar problem. I found a work around. Now afterwards I think the guides were in another layer or something. I don't know.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek Who said Inkscape is intuitive? Vector image editors rarely are sadly. They're complex programs. Guides are not on other layers in Inskcape. They are not real objects technically. When you export the image, or view the SVG, the guides will not be visible anyway. They're just guides. If there's something you think could be improved in Inkscape you can request it as feature or report a bug in https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/

Comment: @BillyKerr I don't know who did say that Inkscape is intuitive. At least it wasn't me. I don't understand what you want to say with this comment. I just said that the intuitive way does not work. This does not contain any statement about whether inkscape is intuitive or not.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek -  It's a retorical question. But you did say "the intuitive way of deleting".  All I am saying is that complex software is rarely "intuitive". The more advanced features software has, the less intuitive it becomes. A sad fact of life unfortunately.  All we as designers can do is try to find ways to work with the tools we have.  Inkscape is generally very good, and I find it more intuitive than others in some respects, and less so in other ways - it's certainly not perfect, and no software is.

Comment: Anyway, here https://www.reddit.com/r/Inkscape/comments/vcxg7q/delete_all_guides_greyed_out/ I found that some people had a similar problem and here https://goinkscape.com/how-to-remove-all-guides-in-inkscape/ the workaround. Magically the second time just pressing the backspace or the delete key on the keyboard worked.

Answer (score 3):

Okay as soon as I posted this I appear to have found at least one solution...

1. Duplicate the shape with the curve
2. Edit path by nodes, select the node you want the tangent of
3. Use Ctrl+Alt or it's equivalent to drag the node of the duplicated shape tangentially from the original
4. Make a path cusped to the original node and the dragged node, and ideally you can work out the rest of the path from that segment

While this does work, it seems a bit of a bodge... Surely if one can snap a line to a tangent, and drag a node along a tangent, one should be able to simply start a line from a tangent.